# How to handle Activity.onActivityResult() with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement [sign-in hints](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-hints) in my Android app using Jetpack Compose, but this API requires an `Activity` to work.

```
fun showPhoneNumberHint(activity: Activity) {
    val hintRequest: HintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
        .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
        .build()

    val intent = Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent(apiClient, hintRequest)
    val requestCode = 12345

    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(activity, intent.intentSender, requestCode, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
    } catch (exception: SendIntentException) {
        // Error handling
    }
}
```

So I guess that I'll have to pass the Activity object all the way down to the Composable where it's needed, which doesn't seem very clean but it should work.

But now the result of the hint will be received in the Activity's `onActivityResult()` and I'm not sure what the right way is to get it back to the Composable where it's needed.

Is there some clean/standard/alternative way to do this? Preferably I'd just keep all of this logic contained inside the Composable.

Comment: You can use rememberLauncherForActivityResult

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ended up using `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` in combination with the  `ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()` contract to listen for the result. This returns a `launcher` that can be used to start the intent.

Instead of `Auth.CredentialsApi`, which requires the deprecated `GoogleApiClient`, I'm now using the `Credentials.getClient`. For this I still needed an `Activity` which I got using `LocalContext.current`.

```
val phoneNumberHintLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
) {
    if (it.resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
        return@rememberLauncherForActivityResult
    }

    val credential: Credential? = it.data?.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
    val hintResult = credential?.id

    if (hintResult !== null) {
        phoneNumber = hintResult
    }
}

val context = LocalContext.current

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val hintRequest: HintRequest = HintRequest.Builder()
        .setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true)
        .build()

    val phoneNumberHintIntent = Credentials.getClient(context)
        .getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest)

    phoneNumberHintLauncher.launch(
        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(phoneNumberHintIntent)
            .build()
    )
}
```

Comment: I have a new problem here, you can see if you can solve it, thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321018/jetpack-compose-onactivityresult-form-interface

Comment: Is there some way to pass flags to `rememberLauncherForActivityResult`

Comment: @Myzel394, what flags? It is a callback. You can add flags into `intent`.

Answer (score 8):

`Activity.onActivityResult()` is deprecated and you shouldn't use it even without compose. You should use the Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX Activity and Fragment.

The Activity Result APIs provide a `registerForActivityResult()` API for registering the result callback. `registerForActivityResult()` takes an `ActivityResultContract` and an `ActivityResultCallback` and returns an `ActivityResultLauncher` which you’ll use to launch the other activity.

Example without compose:

```
val getContent = registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    // Handle the returned Uri
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // ...

    val selectButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.select_button)

    selectButton.setOnClickListener {
        // Pass in the mime type you'd like to allow the user to select
        // as the input
        getContent.launch("image/*")
    }
}
```

In compose use `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()` instead of `registerForActivityResult`:

```
val result = remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicturePreview()) {
    result.value = it
}

Button(onClick = { launcher.launch() }) {
    Text(text = "Take a picture")
}

result.value?.let { image ->
    Image(image.asImageBitmap(), null, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth())
}
```

The problem with the API you're trying to use is it requires the use of onActivityResult. So, you have no other option but to use it. Try opening an issue on github requesting to update their API.

Comment: I have a new problem here, you can see if you can solve it, thank you very much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71321018/jetpack-compose-onactivityresult-form-interface