# How to observe onActivityResult() in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to implement `Change location settings` to enable gps setting
from here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings

it says `check the result in onActivityResult()` but i don't how to observe the result in jetpack compose. Please Tell me how to observe this result in compose

```
task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    if (exception is ResolvableApiException){
        // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
        // by showing the user a dialog.
        try {
            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
            exception.startResolutionForResult(this@MainActivity,
                    REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS)
        } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
            // Ignore the error.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would use `rememberLauncherForActivityResult()`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67177271/115145

Answer (score 10):

if someone needs the answer

```
    val settingResultRequest =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) {activityResult->
            if (activityResult.resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                Log.d("appDebug", "Accepted")
            else {
                Log.d("appDebug", "Denied")
            }
        }

    task.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
        if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
            try {
                val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest.Builder(exception.resolution).build()
                settingResultRequest.launch(intentSenderRequest)
            } catch (sendEx: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
```