# How to handle callbacks in Jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am migrating my multiple activity app to single activity app.

In the activity I am observing a live data from view model. When the observable triggers, I start a payment activity from a third party SDK as shown below.

```kotlin
onCreate() {
  viewmodel.orderCreation.observe {
    thirdpartysdk.startPaymentWithThisOrder(context)
  }
}


onActivityResult() {
  // use payment result
}
```

As I will be using a Composable now,

```
@Composable
fun PaymentScreen(onOrderCreated: () -> Unit) {
   val orderCreation by viewmodel.orderCreation.observeAsState()
   
   // How to use order creation once here to call onOrderCreated here only once as composable is called again and again
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67177271/how-to-handle-activity-onactivityresult-with-jetpack-compose) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion:

In your viewmodel, create a function to reset your `orderCreation`. And another field + function to store the payment result.

Something like:

```
fun resetOrderCreation() {
    _orderCreation.value = null
}

fun paymentResult(value: SomeType) {
    _paymentResult.value = value
}
```

Now, in your composable, you can do the following:

```
@Composable
fun PaymentScreen(onOrderCreated: () -> Unit) {
    // 1
    val orderCreation by viewmodel.orderCreation.observeAsState()
    var paymentResult by viewmodel.paymentResult.observeAsState()
    // 2  
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        PaymentActivityResultContract()
    ) { result ->
        viewModel.paymentResult(result)
    }

    ...
    // 3
    LaunchedEffect(orderCreation) {
        if (orderCreation != null) {
            launcher.launch()
            viewModel.resetOrderCreation()
        }
    }
    // 4
    if (paymentStatus != null) {
        // Show some UI showing the payment status
    }
}
```

Explaining the code:

1. I'm assuming that you're using `LiveData`. But I really suggest you move to `StateFlow` instead. See more [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow).
2. You will probably need to write a [`ActivityResultContact`](https://nglauber.medium.com/startactivityforresult-e-requestpermissions-no-jetpack-compose-6e7754346802) to your third party lib. I wrote [a post](https://nglauber.medium.com/startactivityforresult-e-requestpermissions-no-jetpack-compose-6e7754346802) about (it's in Portuguese, but I think you can get the idea translating it to English).
3. As soon the `orderCreation` has changed, the `LaunchedEffect` block will run, then you can start the third party activity using `launcher.launch()` (the parameters for this call are defined in your `ActivityResultContract`).
4. Finally, when the payment status changed, you can show something different to the user.